# mysql joining two table

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
table user:
id_u*   f_name   l_name
----------------------
1       andi     mitchel
2       sarah    bench
3       kirsty   larx

table voucher:
id_v*   id_user    id_target
1       1          2
2       2          3
```

quite confused how to join those table with two foreign keys

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM voucher v 
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id_u = v.id_user
LEFT JOIN user u1 ON u1.id_u = v.id_target
WHERE .... ")
```

echoing while loop... and returns nothing??

```
while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
   echo  $r['u.f_name'];
   echo  $r['u1.f_name'];
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JOIN` seems absolutely correct. The only issue is that you have joined table `user` twice, therefore you have columns with same name (like `f_name`). The database will assign different (but arbitrary) names to these columns. You can override this behaviour with the `AS` keyword:

```
$db->query("SELECT v.*
                 , u.f_name AS user_f_name
                 , u.l_name AS user_l_name
                 , ta.f_name AS target_f_name
                 , ta.l_name AS target_l_name
            FROM voucher v 
            LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id_u = v.id_user
            LEFT JOIN user ta ON ta.id_u = v.id_target
            WHERE .... ")
```

Then:

```
while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
   echo  $r['user_f_name'];
   echo  $r['target_f_name'];
endwhile;
```

And I think you can replace the `LEFT JOIN`s with (inner) `JOIN`s. Unless you have `id_user` or `id_target` values referencing non-existing userids (`id_u`).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are asking for all people who are in the voucher table regardless of them being in position 1 (user) or position 2 (target)... Then, showing that person's name.

This query does a pre-query of each possible person and their position basis (via WhichPosition).

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      AllVoucherUsers.WhatPosition,
      u.*
   FROM
      ( select distinct 
              v.id_user, 
             '1' as WhatPosition
           from voucher v
        union select distinct
             v.id_target as id_user,
             '2' as WhatPosition
           from voucher v
      ) AllVoucherUsers
      join users u
         on AllVoucherUsres.id_user = u.id_u
```

If you only want ONE instance of a given person -- REGARDLESS of their position, just strip out all instances of the "WhatPosition" reference...

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      u.*
   FROM
      ( select distinct 
              v.id_user
           from voucher v
        union select distinct
             v.id_target as id_user
           from voucher v
      ) AllVoucherUsers
      join users u
         on AllVoucherUsres.id_user = u.id_u
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM voucher v 
    LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id_u = v.id_user OR u.id_u = v.id_target
    WHERE ....
```

Comment: i tried that one, but still return nothing. and how do i echoing the result for id_user and id_target user?

Comment: @its the above query. i want to echo the name for id_user and id_target, those two different user :)

Answer (score -1):

how about:
SELECT * FROM voucher JOIN user ON id_user = id_u

Simpler still:

SELECT * FROM voucher, user WHERE id_user = id_u

Comment: He wants to "resolve" id_user and id_target (both are different users)